# java recursion: object is replaced rather than adding a new one

Tags: java

I am trying to add an object inside an object using recursion. My object contains an arrayList and I am trying to add my objects to this arrayList. But instead of adding a new object, my objects are being replaced.

My code which is doing this: This is where the logic of adding an object is being done. But it is being replaced instead.

```
private ArrayList<SubChapters> recursiveSubChapters(ReportingTree tree, LinkedHashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> linkedHashMap, Boolean isSubTree){
SubChapters subChapters = new Subchapters();
ArrayList<SubChapters> alchildUnits = new ArrayList<SubChapters>();
    final String chapterId = linkedHashMap.get(tree.getUnitID()).get("unit_num");       
    final String chapterName= linkedHashMap.get(tree.getUnitID()).get("unit_name");

        if (!isSubTree) {
            subChapters.set(chapterId);
            subChapters.setTreeName(chapterName);
        } 
        final ArrayList<ReportingTree> branches = tree.getBranches();
        if (branches != null) {
            subChapters.hasSubUnits(true);
            for (ReportingTree subTree: branches) {
                subChapters.setSubChapters(recursiveSubChapters(subTree, linkedHashMap, false));
//This is where the logic of adding an object is being done. But it is being replaced instead.  
            }
            alchildUnits.add(subChapters);
        } 
        return alchildUnits;
    }
```

My guess is that I am messing somewhere in the loop here but I am not able to figure out where I am messing up. Thanks in advance for any suggestions or help.

My subChapters class:

```
public String subChapterID;
public String subChapterName;
public boolean isSubTree= false;
public ArrayList<SubChapters> subChapters;

and getters and setters.
```

I have coded the same solution to return a string and see the order on a jsp. It works just fine. I am not able to apply the same to my issue here.

```
private String recursive(ReportingTree tree, LinkedHashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> listUnitInfo, boolean isTop) {
                    final String unitID = tree.getUnitID();
                    final HashMap<String, String> unit = listUnitInfo.get(unitID);
                    String output = "";
                    if (!isTop) {
                        output += "<li><a href=\"./Display.do?unit=" + unitID + "\">" + unit.get("unit_num") + "/" + unit.get("unit_name") + "</a>";
                    }
                    final ArrayList<ReportingTree> branches = tree.getBranches();
                    if (branches != null) {
                        if (isTop) {
                            output += "<li><a href=\"./Display.do?unit=" + unitID + "\">" + unit.get("unit_num") + "/" + unit.get("unit_name") + "</a>";
                        }
                        output += "<ul>\n";
                        for (ReportingTree subTree : branches) {
                            output += recursive(subTree, listUnitInfo, false);
                        }
                        output += "</ul>";
                    } else {
                        if (isTop) {
                            output += "<li>No units match your criteria.";
                        }
                    }
                    output += "</li>\n";
                    return output;
                }
```

Comment: We aren't going to debug your code for you. There is way too much code and output in your question to make it useful for others. Keep code/output in your question as brief as possible, and identify which part (ideally line) of your code seems to not work.

Comment: Sorry for the extra info. I do not expect someone to debug my code. I have added a comment where I think the mistake is in the code. Hope this helps. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I think the cause is inside the inner for loop. Especially, subChapters.setSubtitles.

Comment: Yes. I know I am missing something inside the inner for loop where an object should be added but it is being replaced.

Comment: Anyway why you declared alchildUnits as ArrayList? According to your code only one subchapter is created in the given method.

Comment: I created alchildUnits as an arraylist because I want to put my objects inside a collection. I want my code to create multiple objects of subChapters. Can you point out where I am doing wrong? Or suggest how I correct it? Thanks.

Comment: Move line 2, 13, 18  into the for loop.  That's my suggestion.

Comment: That one didn't help. I have coded the same problem returning a string and that works perfectly and in the order I want my elements to be in. Now how do I change this code to return an arrayList for my problem?

Comment: Why don't you show us the code of `SubChapters.setSubtitle()`?

Comment: I'm sorry for the typo. My bad. It is subChapters.setSubChapters. The setter inside the subChapters class.

Comment: you're initializing subchapters only once... you need to do it inside the for, before the setSubChapters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is subChapters.setSubChapters, what I think you're trying to do is
subChapters.addSubChapters.

The reason why it works with the strings is because you're using += to add
the new string to the old string. Doing setSubChapters would be the same as using = with the strings.

addSubChapters would be a method that should add something to an ArrayList variable inside your subChapters class.